# RowMatrix, MLlib, Java Spark

Tags: java, matrix, apache-spark

I have [RowMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/distributed/RowMatrix.html) and my question is, how I can manipulate it by indicies? This question is very simillar to this one:

[Matrix Operation in Spark MLlib in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944504/matrix-operation-in-spark-mllib-in-java)

Finally, everything, what I need is to have the Matrix with the good class library. Currently I can't manipulate this object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the JavaDocs of `RowMatrix` indicate

> :: Experimental :: Represents a row-oriented distributed Matrix with no meaningful row indices.

There is no ordering on the rows. You can obtain a `breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix` from it by calling `toBreeze`, but you have no guaranteed ordering of the rows. They are just inserted in the resulting matrix as they arrive at the master. This means that the results of this operation can vary from time to time.

If you need a deterministic outcome of the `toBreeze` operation, then you have to use an `IndexedRowMatrix`. There every row has a row index assigned which is used to build the `breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix`.

From there you can then use the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28944504/4815083), which is

```scala
import no.uib.cipr.matrix.DenseMatrix;
// ...
IndexedRowMatrix U = svd.U();
DenseMatrix U_mtj = new DenseMatrix((int) U.numCols(), (int) U.numRows(), U.toBreeze().toArray$mcD$sp(), true);
// From there, matrix operations are available on U_mtj
```

Comment: I think the API has changed, `toBreeze` seems to have been moved to `linalg.Matrices` and made private to that package. I can't find a way to convert `RowMatrix` to a `breeze` matrix.